# Can't we say that "some numbers are not real" is the negation of "all numbers are real"?

Tags: logic

Refer to this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNeISigUCo0&list=PL0862D1A947252D20&index=4
On 52:49, can't we say that "some numbers are not real" is the negation of "all numbers are real"?

Comment: Yes; "not all" is the same as "some are not"

Comment: Yes, you are right. But what is your point?

Comment: The professor doesn't say anything to indicate that this would not be the case, so it's difficult to understand why you're asking this question

Answer (score 0):

The statement on the board in the linked video at the relevant time is
$$
\lnot \forall x(\operatorname{num}(x) \implies \operatorname{real}(x)),
$$
where $\operatorname{num}(x)$ means "$x$ is a number" and $\operatorname{real}(x)$ means "$x$ is a real number". While it is not relevant to what the professor is saying in the lecture, it is indeed the case that this is equivalent to the statement "some numbers are not real". In particular, we can manipulate the expression as follows:
$$
\lnot \forall x(\operatorname{num}(x) \implies \operatorname{real}(x)) \iff\\
\lnot \forall x(\lnot\operatorname{num}(x) \lor \operatorname{real}(x)) \iff\\
\exists x \lnot(\lnot\operatorname{num}(x) \lor \operatorname{real}(x)) \iff\\
\exists x (\lnot\lnot\operatorname{num}(x) \land \lnot \operatorname{real}(x)) \iff\\
\exists x (\operatorname{num}(x) \land \lnot \operatorname{real}(x)).
$$